# C++ How to convert a binary tree into a binary search tree without using extra space

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-search-tree

This C++ assignment requires us to create a binary tree and check to see if it is a binary search tree. If it isn't, then we need an algorithm to repair it WITHOUT using extra space or other data structures. My friends and I are all stuck on figuring out a proper algorithm because tons of searching online has come up with little to nothing. We don't care much about runtime, we are mostly focused on figuring out how to repair a BT with the given requirements.

Linked lists are used to create the trees but we're stumped on how to implement some kind of algorithm to convert it into a BST.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Balanced binary search tree, or just a BST? If it just has to be a binary tree, simply create a completely left-biased tree and then sort the elements with an arbitrary algorithm. But I guess you're looking for a balanced tree.

Comment: No it doesn't have to be balanced, but what exactly do you mean by an arbitrary algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps given below:

1. Check your binary tree `T1` is a Binary Search Tree or not. If Yes, no need to worry about, else goto step 2
2. Do the **post-order traversal** of the given Binary Tree and create another Tree `T2`*(consider it as Binary Search Tree initially pointing to NULL, means empty initially)*.
3. While doing the post-order traversal of the Binary Tree, keep on deleting the nodes one by one and create a copy of each node and insert that node to the BST `T2` one by one. (NOTE: The insertion should be done in BST manner)

**Complexity:**
Worst-Time Complexity: **O(n<sup>2</sup>).**
Space Complexity: **O(1).** *constant*

Comment: unfortunately we can't create any new data structures when repairing the tree

Comment: @eunoia. look closely you are not creating any new data structure, you are just repairing it without any extra effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following steps to convert your binary tree into binary search tree in place:

1. First we will convert the binary tree into a doubly linked list. Do an inorder traversal and change the left and right pointers (left can be used as next and right as previous) accordingly to form a linked list in place.
2. Then sort the linked list in place(use merge sort here as it sorts a linked list in place).
3. Then u can convert this linked list in place back to a tree. Start with root as middle element of linked list and use a recursive function to move left and right accordingly.

This will create a balanced tree.